# Binding textbox with list of items

Tags: binding, textbox, windows-phone-7

I am trying to create my first app for Windows Phone 7.

I have a Detail View and the .cs class associated with the view.

In my view, I have :

```
  <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
  <TextBlock Name="textBlock1" Text="..."/>
  </StackPanel>
```

In the .cs:

```
  ...
  listAgences = new List<Agence>();

  Agence agence1 = new Agence();
  agence1.Name = "test";
  agence1.Adresse = "test1";
  ...
  listAgences.Add(agence1);
  ...
```

How do I get to have the Text in the textbox to be "test"?

I tried stuff like:

```
  Text="{Binding Path=listAgences[0].Name}";
```

I know how to do this in `ASP.NET`, but here I'm quite lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming that your datacontext class has a public property `List<Agence> ListAgences { get; set; }` then binding like that should work, though.

Comment: its week end now, i'll try again this way on thursday. i did it from .cs file like : textBlock1=listAgences[0].Name; Though i want to generate the texdBlocks in the interface depending on how many items i have in my list. Right now i have 3 textblocks because my list have 3 hard coded agences. whe  i'll use my webservice i won't do that anymore. in mvc.NEt with a template i would do something like that in aspx  <%: foreach agence in listAgences  { setup UI} %>. i don't know how to do that in xaml

Comment: hi john, it doesn't work the way i've written it. Declaration of my list in the .cs file: public List<Agence> listAgences { get; set; } .

Comment: what do you call "Datacontext class"? i assume its the xaml and the .cs file associated to it.

Comment: the "DataContext" is the object set as the datacontext on the ui component.  the trivialist way to set the datacontext is to do it in the constructor of the class, `DataContext=this;` right before InitializeComponent().  Then anything that uses data binding in that class will reference properties on the thing itself.

Comment: thank you very much John. it works as you told me ,when i add the Datacontext=this. i have another question i'm gonna create another post. if you want to take a look... thx again